# Unable to edit others about me in graph api

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently trying to manipulate the "***aboutMe***" field of a user. See:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I am able to edit my own ***aboutMe*** field, but not that of others. Am I missing a permission? Is there a reason I can't edit the property of others? In the "update user" documentation it says:

```
To update the following properties, you must specify them in their own PATCH request, 
without including the other properties listed in the table above: aboutMe, birthday, 
interests, mySite, pastProjects, responsibilities, schools, and skills.
```

This is the request I am currently trying:

[image]

And this is the response I am getting:

[image]

Comment: You need to generate access token using **delegated** flows by signing with that user account and patch `aboutme` by calling /me endpoint.

Comment: I am using delegated flows. Even with delegated flows I cannot edit other people's aboutMe. I don't have a single permission with application rights

Comment: You cannot update other people's `aboutMe`. Properties like aboutMe, birthday, 
interests, mySite, pastProjects, responsibilities, schools, and skills are restricted to be updated by others and can only updated by user itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must be assigned at least **User Administrator** role to be able to edit properties of others.

Required permissions are `Directory.ReadWrite.All` and `User.ReadWrite.All`.

Answer (score 0):

> **Note that** properties like aboutMe, birthday, interests, mySite, pastProjects, responsibilities, schools and skills can **only** be
> updated by **signed-in user** itself not by others even if they have
> Administrator roles.

Initially, I generated **access token** using authorization code flow by signing with *Global Administrator* account via Postman like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code: code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran below PATCH request with token generated with user having Global Administrator role, I too got **same error** as below:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/sri@xxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com
{
    "aboutMe" : "test"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, you need to generate access token by signing
> in with  user account for which you want to update `aboutMe` field and
> run **PATCH** request calling **`/me`** endpoint.

You can decode the token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) and check **`upn`** and **`scp`** claims for **confirmation** like this:

[image]

When I used above token in calling **`/me`** endpoint via **PATCH** request, I got response successfully as below:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
{
    "aboutMe" : "test"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

With roles like *User Administrator* or *Global Administrator*, you can update **sensitive properties** like accountEnabled, mobilePhone etc.. of other users but not **`aboutMe`** property.

**Reference:**
[Update user - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-body)